# How can i preserve the ASCII encoding when loading xml with XDocument.Parse?

Tags: encoding, ascii, linq-to-xml

When I load an xml document with encoding="us-ascii" using XDocument.Parse, the resultant document has converted the ascii into utf-8.

For example, in my xml file i have (not full file)

```
<data>&#233; some other stuff</data>
```

When this is loaded, it converts to

```
<data>é some other stuff</data>
```

How can I prevent this? I need to be able to later select descendant and re-write them to another file, but when doing so, it's converted.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the conversion? They're equivalent XML files and should be treated as equivalent by anything processing them.

Comment: well, unfortunately, the end processor that accepts the xml does not treat them the same. It's not something I can change or have changed.